# Youtube embed video does not show in Fraction slider (Drupal 7)

Tags: module, drupal-7, slider, youtube-iframe-api

I use FractionSlider module for my website. I want to add youtube video in my slider. Here is my code.

```
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
    <div class="responisve-container">

        <div class="slider">
          <div class="fs_loader"></div>

          <div class="slide">
            <img src="/product/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_business/images/slider/banner_4.jpg" width="1920" height="auto" data-in="fade" data-out="fade" />
            <p class="claim" data-position="20,390" data-in="top" data-out="top" data-step="1">
                <iframe allowfullscreen="true" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0DPdy98e4c" style="min-width:1000px;"></iframe>
            </p>
          </div>

          <div class="slide">
            <img src="/product/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_business/images/slider/banner_1.jpg" width="1920" height="auto" data-in="fade" data-out="fade" />
             <p class="claim slide-heading" data-position="160,430" data-in="top" data-out="top" data-ease-in="easeOutBounce" data-step="1" data-delay="60"><span class="banner-uni">Hello Testing 1</span></p>
          </div>

          <div class="slide">
            <img src="/product/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_business/images/slider/banner_1.jpg" width="1920" height="auto" data-in="fade" data-out="fade" />
             <p class="claim slide-heading" data-position="160,430" data-in="top" data-out="top" data-ease-in="easeOutBounce" data-step="1" data-delay="60"><span class="banner-uni">Hello Testing 2</span></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I put video slide at the first position.There are 3 slides currently running automatically at first round.

After first round is finish, then goes to first slide (youtube video slide). The problem is that the slide does not slide automatically to next one (second slide) and it's stopped in youtube slide. That is only happening in second round. Not first round.

I suspect that it is caused by youtube video embed. So, I remove it and test again. It goes automatically again. I replace the Facebook video link in youtube video link. It works but I prefer to put youtube link.

Comment: Hi. Which module are you using ? This one [Views FractionSlider](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_fractionslider) ?

Comment: Yes bro. @ClaudiuChirilov